# Find Window to search string in richtextbox in winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have written a winform application  where i have a form with richtextbox control populated with string. I need to search specific pattern of string from the the string in the richtextbox control when user presses ctr+F just like we Find specific pattern of string in notepad++. Do i need to create the Find window by myself or is there any default Find window control which I can use?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think the question is particularily unclear. I have exactly the same problem, googled it, came here, recognize it's exactly the thing I was wondering (is there a built-in functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a window that finds the specific character/word or sentence what you want. Windows Form Control doesn't provide any kind of UI facility to find your string. It is also depends on that from where you want to find the string. you must have an editor like Textbox, RichTextbox or any control which contains string values like DataGridView, WebBrowser Control, ListView etc. but, each control can have their own method to find a specific string. for example if you want to find a string in RichTextBox then you have to call the method from that particular control (`richTextBox1.Find(...)`). You can't find the string from all controls globally.

If you want to implement the feature in particular control like `TextEditor` (Word Pad) then there is an example on Code Project site that you can refer.
[RichTextBox Control with Find functionality](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32793/RichTextBox-Control-with-Find-functionality)

Comment: So, I guess there is no Find Dialogue in winforms. I have to create my own.

Comment: exactly, you have to create it your own window as the defined in given example.